# In how many ways can I distribute $9$ toys equally among $3$ children.

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can I distribute $9$ toys equally among $3$ children?

My attempt was $$\binom{9}{3}\times\binom{6}{3}\times\binom{3}{3}=1680$$
but that appears to be wrong since it's not in the options. The options are: $280$, $300$, $320$, $480$, $504$. Can I get a help on this?

Comment: Are the $9$ toys all distinct?  If so, I agree with your result (and, of course, the problem isn't interesting if the toys are all the same).

Comment: The question doesn't specify about the toys being distinct or not, so I just assumed they all are. And yes! The question would be dull if all the toys were the same

Comment: The same question can be asked about if the children are distinct or not.  They ought to be distinct... children have different names, hopes, and desires typically... but it is possible that either the question author intended otherwise or incorrectly assumed otherwise in their calculations.  In that case (*which I strongly disagree with*) we would have an answer of $\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}\times \frac{1}{3!} = 280$... seen by using your original calculation followed by dividing by $3!$ to "forget" which kid was which, thereby treating them as the same.

Comment: Following on @JMoravitz comment, perhaps the interpretation in the author's mind was more like: In how many ways can I distribute $9$ toys into equal groups, for $3$ children?

So not really caring which child gets which set of toys, but rather whether the collection of the sets is same of different for different distributions. But I agree your answer is the best one for the original wording.